# Отсутствие перевода в меню тревоги на комментарии

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, комментарии, тревоги

1. Тревога на комментарий на мете
2. Отозвать тревогу
3. Снова нажать тревогу
4. ...
5. Непереведённая фраза *"You have already raised this type of flag and can no longer reraise it"*

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавил перевод:

- https://ru.traducir.win/strings/13067

Появится на сайте в свежих сборках. Текущая rev 2020.8.18.37425